# Installing relevant packages for Lean's math lib

Tags: lean, lean3, lean-mathlib

I'm using the Lean computer proof assistant on my Mac.

I tried to import data.nat.basic from lean's documentation, just like this:

```
import data.nat.basic
```

I get this:

```
could not resolve import: data.nat.basic
All Messages (2)
Topologic.lean:1:0
file 'data/nat/basic' not found in the search path
Use 'lean --path' to see where lean is looking, or https://leanprover-community.github.io/file-not-found.html for more
Topologic.lean:6:1
invalid import: data.nat.basic
could not resolve import: data.nat.basic
```

Evidently I missed the memo on one of the relevant installations and it means I can't use math lib. Basically I want to be able to use hash maps and lists from lean's math lib.

Can anyone direct me towards a tutorial for installing the relevant files for lists and hash sets? I am going to guess this involves installing math lib packages.

I've never actually worked with GitHub before so I would be grateful if someone had a link to a complete set of instructions.

Further, it seems like the instructions for Mathlib installation don't work- I get an error message printed in the comments below.

Comment: You can find lean/mathlib install instructions at https://leanprover-community.github.io/get_started.html

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Did you try this on an M1 Mac? That's what I have, and on steps 3 and 4 I get "error: binary package was not provided for 'darwin'". Evidently someone else had the same problem here: https://leanprover-community.github.io/archive/stream/113488-general/topic/mathlib.20branches.html

Answer (score 2):

(Here are some general instructions for installing Lean 3 and setting up a project with mathlib, but for your specific problem, you may need to get help on the Lean zulip chat.)

### Installing Lean 3 and other stuff

As Mario said, the installation instructions for Lean 3 can be found at [Getting Started with Lean](https://leanprover-community.github.io/get_started.html).  Since you mention you are on an M1 mac, the directions are here: [M1 Macs / Apple Silicon](https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/macos.html#m1-macs--apple-silicon).  Unfortunately, setting of Lean (and many other software tools) on M1 macs can be error prone, so feel free to stop by the Lean Zulip for more one-on-one support.

### Setting up a lean project to use `mathlib`

Once Lean is installed you will want to make a Lean project which will allow you not only to use the base lean library, but also Lean's main mathematical library `mathlib` (which is where `data.nat.basic` comes from).  Those instructions can be found in [Lean projects](https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/project.html), but let me give you some guidance.

(And for future readers, this is for Lean 3.  Setting up projects for Lean 4 is different.)

When you want to start a new Lean project, in a terminal, go to the directory you want to create your project in, e.g.

```bash
cd ~/Documents/lean_projects
```

Then enter the following to make a new project titled `my_awesome_project`:

```bash
leanproject new my_awesome_project
```

To start VS code in your project, either start VS Code up manually, select "Open..." and navigate to `my_awesome_project`, or if you installed VS Code from homebrew you can also do:

```bash
code my_awesome_project
```

By making a Lean 3 project you will have added a number of files and directories:

- `.gitignore` (and other git stuff): This is a git project which will let your save progress and upload your project to github
- `src`: This is where you Lean files go.
- `_target`: This is where the mathlib files are stored along with their compiled `.olean` files.  Don't touch this.
- `leanpkg.path` and `leanpkg.toml`: These are lean configuration files. Usually you don't need to touch them, especially if you use `leanproject` to do all of your upgrading, etc.

If things are set up correctly, then you can make a new `my_awesome_file.lean` file in `src` and start to type in valid lean.